# Does dnsmasq automatically update when running as a dhcp server as well?

Tags: dns, dhcp, dnsmasq

I want to set up dnsmasq on a Raspberry Pi to use as a DNS server for my home network. My goal is to have a setup where when a new device is connected to the home network, it can be addressed by its hostname **without modification to anything on the Pi**

So as an example, say I have a machine with "mymachine" in /etc/hostsname, and I then plug it in to my network with an ethernet cable (and tell it where the DNS server is of course). I should then be able to go to some other machine on the network and do `ping mymachine.lan.mydomain` and have it ping mymachine. So I guess for this to work the DHCP server would updated the DNS server?

Does dnsmasq do this automatically when it is set up to be the DHCP server for the LAN as well?

Answer (score 0):

After setting this up, the answer is yes, it does.